# How to get answers to natural language questions from freebase?

Tags: ruby, freebase, nlp-question-answering

I have massive amounts of natural language questions in the format of "Subject-entity [tab] relationship [tab] Object-entity [tab] question" as follows:

```
www.freebase.com/m/01jp8ww  www.freebase.com/music/album/genre  www.freebase.com/m/01qzt1   Which genre of album is harder.....faster?
www.freebase.com/m/0np6z99  www.freebase.com/music/album/release_type   www.freebase.com/m/02lx2r   what format is fearless
www.freebase.com/m/0wzc58l  www.freebase.com/people/person/place_of_birth   www.freebase.com/m/0n2z what city was alex golfis born in
www.freebase.com/m/0jtw9c   www.freebase.com/film/writer/film   www.freebase.com/m/05szq8z  what film is by the writer phil hay?
www.freebase.com/m/0gys2sn  www.freebase.com/people/deceased_person/place_of_death  www.freebase.com/m/0tzls    Where did roger marquis die
www.freebase.com/m/01fwty   www.freebase.com/people/deceased_person/cause_of_death  www.freebase.com/m/0gk4g    what was the cause of death of yves klein
www.freebase.com/m/02cft    www.freebase.com/location/location/people_born_here www.freebase.com/m/0k8n4c1  Which equestrian was born in dublin?
www.freebase.com/m/01htzx   www.freebase.com/tv/tv_genre/programs   www.freebase.com/m/04g1jv6  What is a tv action show?
```

How does one parse these natural language question files to obtain the answer to the question? I am planning on using ruby to parse these millions upon millions of questions, although I am a bit stuck on how to actually obtain the answers to the questions in the files from freebase.

From what I have viewed from the direct links, there doesn't to seem to actually be an answer to the question located in them, so is there some other method to obtaining the answers?